# RowFactory.Create throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to change my JavaRDD of String to JavaRDD of Row. In the step I change the String to Row. The program always crush.

```
 JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.parallelize(row_string);
 JavaRDD<Row> rdd =  lines.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Override
 public Row call(String line) {
       String[] split = line.split(",");
       System.out.println(split.length);
       return RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList(split));
     }
 });
```

Can someone points out where I go wrong?

Comment: Can you post the exception.

Comment: Are you getting any serializable exception?

Comment: Also please paste the sample string which you are trying to split.